# How to create custom views (style&html) in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

How to create a custom style for a view in drupal 8? For example I have 3 diffrent views and all of them should render a diffrent html moreover I would like to add a text above the table?

I can replace "views/views-view.html.twig" but it will have an effect on all views

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a custom style for a view

You can assign a custom class to a specific View on View's settings page:

[image]

and then add desired styles for this class to your theme's *style.css* file.

> I would like to add a text above the table

It could be done via View's settings too, just add new items to a *HEADER* section:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's one of the solution but I would like to have even more freedom in customaizing view. For example I would like to change html of any field views-view-fields.html.twig.

Comment: I guess then you should use Views API https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/group/views_overview/8.2.x Not an expert in it, so can't suggest any further, sorry.